# Sticky menu Font size

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm very new to css. When we scroll down, I would like to keep the font size the same but I'm not sure how to do this with css.

https://www.cabasse.com/

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    #et-secondary-nav .menu-item-has-children>a:first-child, #top-menu .menu-item-has-children>a:first-child {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6)!important;
        padding: inherit;
    }
    
    .et_header_style_left #et-top-navigation, .et_header_style_split #et-top-navigation {
        padding-top: 33px !important;
    }
    
    #top-menu li a {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6)!important;
    }
    #et_search_icon:before{
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6)!important;
    }
.et_fixed_nav.et_show_nav #page-container, .et_non_fixed_nav.et_transparent_nav.et_show_nav #page-container {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`et-fixed-header` class added on the scroll, you have change CSS using et-fixed-header class like below

```
body .et-fixed-header #top-menu li a {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Hope it works!